# Micropython Socket Server HTTP response with HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, micropython

Ok, so I'm working with an esp8266 flashed with micropython and am writing a socket based web server. It's all working so far. When I go to the right IP address and port combination in my web browser I get an HTTP response from my server which includes the HTML I expect.

Here's where I'm stuck. As my web application becomes more complex I would like to separate out my HTML, JS, and CSS files rather than having inline JS and CSS in my HTML. I can't however figure out how I would send these files separately to be referenced by my index.html file.

My non blocking server looks like so:

```
def server_connect(server_socket):
    r, _, __, = select.select((server_socket,), (), (), 0)
    if r:
        for _ in r:
            client, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
            try:
                print("\nConnected to client at {}".format(client_addr))
                request = client.recv(4096)
                print(request)
                print()

                try:
                    with open("index.html", 'rb') as infile:
                        response_body = infile.read()
                except OSError:
                    response_body = b"No index file found..."

                try:
                    with open("test.js", 'rb') as infile:
                        response_body_2 = infile.read()
                except OSError:
                    response_body_2 = b"No js file found."

                response_header = b"HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html; encoding=utf8\n\n"

                client.send(response_header)
                client.sendall(response_body)
                client.sendall(response_body_2)
                client.close()
            
            except OSError:
                pass
```

As can be seen, I'm simply sending the text from two different files back to the client and the results are predictable. My web page shows the HTML formatted as it should be, followed by the JS as plain text after that.

My understanding, though limited, is that with a typical web server multiple files would be sent in response to multiple requests. My thought process, therefore, is that I need to send my HTML and JS files back to separate requests from the same client. So perhaps my question is how do I let the client know that I have additional files to send so that the client can in turn make the requests that will allow my server to send those files.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A browser reads your html with one HTTP GET and then by reading the HTML generates HTTP GET for all the referenced files - JS, CSS, images - automatically. All you have to do is provide the references in the HTML, <script> tags for JS, css stylesheet references, etc.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, that makes sense. I am enlightened. Thank you!